# Explicit loading - java.lang.ClassLoader

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

In first case, For explicit loading of `test.ClassLoaderTest` using below code,

```
public ClassLoaderTest{
      public static void main(String[] args){
        .....
        Class.forName("test.ClassLoaderTest", true,
                          ClassLoaderTest.class.getClassLoader().getParent());
        ....
      }
```

`findClass()` method  of `Launcher$ExtClassLoader` instance gets invoked to load `test.ClassLoaderTest` with below error due to visibility principle,

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.ClassLoaderTest
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at test.ClassLoaderTest.main(ClassLoaderTest.java:29)
```

---

In second case, On explicit loading of `test.ClassLoaderTest1`, using

```
public ClassLoaderTest{
          public static void main(String[] args){
            .....
            Class.forName("test.ClassLoaderTest1");
            ....
          }
```

`loadClass()` method of `Launcher$AppClassLoader` instance is ultimately used to load `test.ClassLoaderTest1` class,

where `test.ClassLoaderTest1` is a wrong class file that lead to below error,

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.ClassLoaderTest1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at test.ClassLoaderTest1.main(ClassLoaderTest.java:16)
```

---

In both cases, class loading job is done by `java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass()`

---

`Class.forName()` internally invokes `getClassLoader()` to know the class loader that already loaded the class.

In second case, When `Class` gets a class loader instance(of type Launcher$AppClassLoader) by calling 
`ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader0();` to invoke the class loader instance again.

Is `java.lang.ClassLoader` mainly used for sub-classing custom class loader? that load classes not available in CLASSPATH but from network source etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Javadoc,

```
public **abstract** class ClassLoader
extends Object
```

There are different ClassLoader implementations that use different strategies for locating and reading the byte streams that compose a class.